# Django- Exception Type: KeyError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, twitter, beautifulsoup

I'm working on an application where I'm using the Twitter account URL of a user who logs in into my application using Twitter login to scrap the total tweet count and number of followers using `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib2`.

views.py

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fillform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile = ['Tweets', 'Followers']
        followers = ''
        tweets = ''
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
            link = obj.twitter_url
            dic = {}
            r = urllib2.urlopen(link)
            src = r.read()
            res = BeautifulSoup(src)
            for p, d in zip(profile, res.find_all('span', { 'data-is-compact': "true"})):
                dic[p] = d
            followers = dic['Followers']
            tweets = dic['Tweets']  
            obj.twitter_followers = followers
            obj.total_tweets = tweets
            obj.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        #form = EvangelizedForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = EvangelizedForm(initial={'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                                                'twitter_url': 'https://www.twitter.com/' + request.user.username,
                                                    'last_name': request.user.last_name})
        else:
            form = EvangelizedForm()    

    context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user, 'form':form})    

    #return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form, 'context_instance':context})  
    return render_to_response('rango/fillform.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

However, this is the error I'm encountering on a POST request:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Django\GetEvangelized\rango\views.py" in fillform
  30.             followers = dic['Followers']  

Exception Type: KeyError at /rango/fillform/
Exception Value: 'Followers'
```

I have tried running my scraping script locally and the keys `Followers` and `Tweets` do return values stored in the dictionary. What seems to be going wrong in my view? Am I importing the `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib2` modules in Django the wrong way? Or is it something else that's wrong in my approach?

Comment: My guess is `res.find_all('span', { 'data-is-compact': "true"})` returns `None`. Are you familiar with `pdb ` ? If so, you can use that

Comment: @karthikr The same script returns a value when I try running it from a text editor. Why would it return `None` in Django?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi are you running the django project in a separate virtual environment?

Comment: @alecxe The problem was indeed in my BeautifulSoup's `find_all` attributes. The method was returning `None` just as @karthikr mentioned above. So I simply changed the method attributes to something more concrete, and everything works just fine now.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi it could also be because of the parsers `bs4` chooses to parse the HTML - e.g. if you had not `lxml` installed in the virtual env, it would pick `html5lib`, if it was not installed - it would pick the default `html.parser`, see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers.